# Yii - getPathOfAlias inside setPathOfAlias

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to set alias path in Yii to my file upload directory in

testweb
   - ...
   - protected
   - ...
   - myupload

So I put like this in protected/config/main.php:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('upload_dir', Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . '/myupload');
```

But then when I echo the alias, I only get '/myupload'

```
echo Yii::getPathOfAlias('upload_dir'); //only returns /myupload
```

Comment: In which file do you try that? You're probably doing it at a point, where `webroot` isn't defined yet (which happens quite early, though).

Comment: I echo the alias from the view file. I echo Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') in the view file and it returned c:/xampp/htdocs/testweb/

Comment: Yeah, but the question is, where do you call `setPathOfAlias()`.

Comment: I put Yii::setPathOfAlias inside protected/config/main.php, if I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't call `getPathOfAlias()` inside your `main.php` configuration file, because path aliases are created in the [constructor](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#__construct-detail) of [`CApplication`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication). But the constructor wasn't called yet at the point when `main.php` is included.

The right way to configure path aliases, is to use the `aliases` property in your `main.php`. In your case you could do:

```
return array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'upload_dir' => 'webroot.myupload',
    ),
    ...
```

Also note, that you can (and should) make use of the dot notation for aliases.

Comment: Thanks, your code works instead of using setPathOfAlias().
After I set the aliases in the array, I managed to get/echo the alias using getPathOfAlias()

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('upload_dir', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."..".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."myupload");
```

Comment: It returned C:\xampp\htdocs\testweb\protected\config/../../myupload :(

Comment: my applogies i assumed you were using linux just change slashes to windows variety. Or else you can use my latest code

Comment: Not really what I wanted, it returned protected\config\..\..\myupload. I wanted protected\myupload but thanks Michael has the answer :)

Comment: both mean the same thing..if you want only within protected then two \..\ is sufficient.  Yeah his answer is correct, but i prefer to set it without using other aliases, as it works with the boilerplate templates like YiiBoilerplate YiiBooster etc..